# Get text from a TextBlock with linebreaks from wrapping?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, textblock

I've got a TextBlock that I'm displaying on a Canvas, that displays user entered text.

I'd like to get the content of this TextBlock, but I need to get it in such a way that I know where the linebreaks occur, for example:

[image]

From this displayed Textblock, how can I get the text and know where the line breaks are?

Also, this is a Windows Store App, so the full .NET framework is not available..

Answer (score 2):

As far I know there is no way to retrieve such information from `TextBlock`, however you could try folowing:

- Get `TextBlock` width
- Retrieve width of your text (e.g. using `FormattedText` class)
- Implement some logic which divide text in lines using text width and `TextBlock` width